# megaraid_sas Kernel Module changes in between

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

I am using an LSI MegaRAID SAS 8708EM2 Raid Controller and am having trouble getting it to work with Debian 10 and Debian 11.

On Debian 9 (Linux Kernel 4.10.9) it still works perfectly but as soon as I upgrade to kernel 4.11.0, the controller is unfortunately no longer recognized.

```
lspci -knn (on Kernel version 4.10.9)

28:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 1078 [1000:0060] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 1078 [1000:1013]
        Kernel driver in use: megaraid_sas
        Kernel modules: megaraid_sas
```

shows that it uses the "megaraid_sas" Kernel module.

```
lsmod | grep "raid" (on Kernel version 4.10.9)
    megaraid_sas          125217  0
    scsi_mod              214600  4 sd_mod,megaraid_sas,libata,sg
```

with the Kernel 4.11.0 the modules don't load until I append

```
scsi_mod
megaraid_sas
```

to the

```
/etc/modules
```

file, then the modules are loaded on the next reboot

```
lsmod | grep "raid" (on Kernel version 4.11.0)
    megaraid_sas          125217  0
    scsi_mod              214600  4 sd_mod,megaraid_sas,libata,sg
```

But the controller doesn't appear in

```
lspci
```

and the Hard drives don't show up in

```
lsblk
```

either!

```
dmesg | grep "pci"

[    0.527223] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.532701] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x03af window]
[    0.532701] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x03e0-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.532702] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x03b0-0x03df window]
[    0.532702] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    0.532703] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.532703] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window]
[    0.532704] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xc0000000-0xfec2ffff window]
[    0.532704] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xfee00000-0xffffffff window]
[    0.532705] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    0.532711] pci 0000:00:00.0: [1022:1480] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.532791] pci 0000:00:00.2: [1022:1481] type 00 class 0x080600
[    0.532892] pci 0000:00:01.0: [1022:1482] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.532961] pci 0000:00:01.3: [1022:1483] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.533046] pci 0000:00:01.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.533101] pci 0000:00:01.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.533120] pci 0000:00:02.0: [1022:1482] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.533191] pci 0000:00:03.0: [1022:1482] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.533256] pci 0000:00:03.1: [1022:1483] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.533340] pci 0000:00:03.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.533394] pci 0000:00:03.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.533411] pci 0000:00:03.2: [1022:1483] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.533495] pci 0000:00:03.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.533549] pci 0000:00:03.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.533569] pci 0000:00:04.0: [1022:1482] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.533640] pci 0000:00:05.0: [1022:1482] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.533711] pci 0000:00:07.0: [1022:1482] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.533776] pci 0000:00:07.1: [1022:1484] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.533850] pci 0000:00:07.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.533898] pci 0000:00:07.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.533919] pci 0000:00:08.0: [1022:1482] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.533984] pci 0000:00:08.1: [1022:1484] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.534065] pci 0000:00:08.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.534115] pci 0000:00:08.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.534155] pci 0000:00:14.0: [1022:790b] type 00 class 0x0c0500
[    0.534270] pci 0000:00:14.3: [1022:790e] type 00 class 0x060100
[    0.534395] pci 0000:00:18.0: [1022:1440] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.534425] pci 0000:00:18.1: [1022:1441] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.534456] pci 0000:00:18.2: [1022:1442] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.534486] pci 0000:00:18.3: [1022:1443] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.534517] pci 0000:00:18.4: [1022:1444] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.534547] pci 0000:00:18.5: [1022:1445] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.534577] pci 0000:00:18.6: [1022:1446] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.534607] pci 0000:00:18.7: [1022:1447] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.534704] pci 0000:03:00.0: [1022:43d0] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.534727] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc5a0000-0xfc5a7fff 64bit]
[    0.534849] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.534893] pci 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.534917] pci 0000:03:00.1: [1022:43c8] type 00 class 0x010601
[    0.534982] pci 0000:03:00.1: reg 0x24: [mem 0xfc580000-0xfc59ffff]
[    0.534992] pci 0000:03:00.1: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfc500000-0xfc57ffff pref]
[    0.535047] pci 0000:03:00.1: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.535095] pci 0000:03:00.2: [1022:43c6] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.535199] pci 0000:03:00.2: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.546016] pci 0000:00:01.3: PCI bridge to [bus 03-26]
[    0.546020] pci 0000:00:01.3:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xdfff]
[    0.546022] pci 0000:00:01.3:   bridge window [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc5fffff]
[    0.546113] pci 0000:20:00.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.546235] pci 0000:20:00.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.546307] pci 0000:20:01.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.546428] pci 0000:20:01.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.546499] pci 0000:20:02.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.546620] pci 0000:20:02.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.546693] pci 0000:20:03.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.546813] pci 0000:20:03.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.546883] pci 0000:20:04.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.547001] pci 0000:20:04.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.547075] pci 0000:20:08.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.547194] pci 0000:20:08.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.547281] pci 0000:03:00.2: PCI bridge to [bus 20-26]
[    0.547287] pci 0000:03:00.2:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xdfff]
[    0.547290] pci 0000:03:00.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc4fffff]
[    0.547339] pci 0000:20:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 21]
[    0.547423] pci 0000:22:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.547452] pci 0000:22:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xd000-0xd0ff]
[    0.547497] pci 0000:22:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xfc404000-0xfc404fff 64bit]
[    0.547525] pci 0000:22:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xfc400000-0xfc403fff 64bit]
[    0.547679] pci 0000:22:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.547679] pci 0000:22:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.558033] pci 0000:20:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 22]
[    0.558040] pci 0000:20:01.0:   bridge window [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.558043] pci 0000:20:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfc400000-0xfc4fffff]
[    0.558096] pci 0000:20:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 23]
[    0.558158] pci 0000:20:03.0: PCI bridge to [bus 24]
[    0.558252] pci 0000:25:00.0: [8086:107d] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.558285] pci 0000:25:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc340000-0xfc35ffff]
[    0.558302] pci 0000:25:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xfc320000-0xfc33ffff]
[    0.558318] pci 0000:25:00.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xc000-0xc01f]
[    0.558383] pci 0000:25:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfc300000-0xfc31ffff pref]
[    0.558517] pci 0000:25:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.558597] pci 0000:25:00.0: disabling ASPM on pre-1.1 PCIe device.  You can enable it with 'pcie_aspm=force'
[    0.558611] pci 0000:20:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 25]
[    0.558617] pci 0000:20:04.0:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    0.558620] pci 0000:20:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfc300000-0xfc3fffff]
[    0.558691] pci 0000:26:00.0: [1b21:1242] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.558727] pci 0000:26:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc207fff 64bit]
[    0.558921] pci 0000:26:00.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.570019] pci 0000:20:08.0: PCI bridge to [bus 26]
[    0.570028] pci 0000:20:08.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc2fffff]
[    0.570130] pci 0000:27:00.0: [10de:1287] type 00 class 0x030000
[    0.570147] pci 0000:27:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfb000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.570163] pci 0000:27:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xe0000000-0xe7ffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.570179] pci 0000:27:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xe8000000-0xe9ffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.570189] pci 0000:27:00.0: reg 0x24: [io  0xf000-0xf07f]
[    0.570199] pci 0000:27:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfc07ffff pref]
[    0.570326] pci 0000:27:00.1: [10de:0e0f] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.570343] pci 0000:27:00.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc080000-0xfc083fff]
[    0.582013] pci 0000:00:03.1: PCI bridge to [bus 27]
[    0.582017] pci 0000:00:03.1:   bridge window [io  0xf000-0xffff]
[    0.582019] pci 0000:00:03.1:   bridge window [mem 0xfb000000-0xfc0fffff]
[    0.582023] pci 0000:00:03.1:   bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xe9ffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.984710] pci 0000:00:03.2: PCI bridge to [bus 28]
[    0.984714] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    0.984716] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc9fffff]
[    0.984761] pci 0000:29:00.0: [1022:148a] type 00 class 0x130000
[    0.984936] pci 0000:00:07.1: PCI bridge to [bus 29]
[    0.984994] pci 0000:2a:00.0: [1022:1485] type 00 class 0x130000
[    0.985158] pci 0000:2a:00.1: [1022:1486] type 00 class 0x108000
[    0.985180] pci 0000:2a:00.1: reg 0x18: [mem 0xfc700000-0xfc7fffff]
[    0.985197] pci 0000:2a:00.1: reg 0x24: [mem 0xfc808000-0xfc809fff]
[    0.985319] pci 0000:2a:00.3: [1022:149c] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.985337] pci 0000:2a:00.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc600000-0xfc6fffff 64bit]
[    0.985440] pci 0000:2a:00.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.985478] pci 0000:2a:00.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.985499] pci 0000:2a:00.4: [1022:1487] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.985510] pci 0000:2a:00.4: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc800000-0xfc807fff]
[    0.985602] pci 0000:2a:00.4: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.985705] pci 0000:00:08.1: PCI bridge to [bus 2a]
[    0.985710] pci 0000:00:08.1:   bridge window [mem 0xfc600000-0xfc8fffff]
[    0.986484] pci 0000:27:00.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    0.986485] pci 0000:27:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.986486] pci 0000:27:00.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.992796] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
[    1.005837] pci 0000:20:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 21]
[    1.005852] pci 0000:20:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 22]
[    1.005854] pci 0000:20:01.0:   bridge window [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    1.005859] pci 0000:20:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfc400000-0xfc4fffff]
[    1.005868] pci 0000:20:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 23]
[    1.005882] pci 0000:20:03.0: PCI bridge to [bus 24]
[    1.005896] pci 0000:20:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 25]
[    1.005898] pci 0000:20:04.0:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    1.005902] pci 0000:20:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfc300000-0xfc3fffff]
[    1.005912] pci 0000:20:08.0: PCI bridge to [bus 26]
[    1.005917] pci 0000:20:08.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc2fffff]
[    1.005926] pci 0000:03:00.2: PCI bridge to [bus 20-26]
[    1.005928] pci 0000:03:00.2:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xdfff]
[    1.005933] pci 0000:03:00.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc4fffff]
[    1.005942] pci 0000:00:01.3: PCI bridge to [bus 03-26]
[    1.005943] pci 0000:00:01.3:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xdfff]
[    1.005946] pci 0000:00:01.3:   bridge window [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc5fffff]
[    1.005952] pci 0000:00:03.1: PCI bridge to [bus 27]
[    1.005953] pci 0000:00:03.1:   bridge window [io  0xf000-0xffff]
[    1.005957] pci 0000:00:03.1:   bridge window [mem 0xfb000000-0xfc0fffff]
[    1.005959] pci 0000:00:03.1:   bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xe9ffffff 64bit pref]
[    1.005963] pci 0000:00:03.2: PCI bridge to [bus 28]
[    1.005964] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    1.005967] pci 0000:00:03.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc9fffff]
[    1.005974] pci 0000:00:07.1: PCI bridge to [bus 29]
[    1.005983] pci 0000:00:08.1: PCI bridge to [bus 2a]
[    1.005986] pci 0000:00:08.1:   bridge window [mem 0xfc600000-0xfc8fffff]
[    1.005992] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x03af window]
[    1.005993] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x03e0-0x0cf7 window]
[    1.005993] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [io  0x03b0-0x03df window]
[    1.005994] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    1.005994] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    1.005994] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 9 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window]
[    1.005995] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 10 [mem 0xc0000000-0xfec2ffff window]
[    1.005995] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 11 [mem 0xfee00000-0xffffffff window]
[    1.005996] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 0 [io  0xc000-0xdfff]
[    1.005996] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc5fffff]
[    1.005997] pci_bus 0000:20: resource 0 [io  0xc000-0xdfff]
[    1.005997] pci_bus 0000:20: resource 1 [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc4fffff]
[    1.005998] pci_bus 0000:22: resource 0 [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    1.005998] pci_bus 0000:22: resource 1 [mem 0xfc400000-0xfc4fffff]
[    1.005998] pci_bus 0000:25: resource 0 [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    1.005999] pci_bus 0000:25: resource 1 [mem 0xfc300000-0xfc3fffff]
[    1.005999] pci_bus 0000:26: resource 1 [mem 0xfc200000-0xfc2fffff]
[    1.006000] pci_bus 0000:27: resource 0 [io  0xf000-0xffff]
[    1.006000] pci_bus 0000:27: resource 1 [mem 0xfb000000-0xfc0fffff]
[    1.006001] pci_bus 0000:27: resource 2 [mem 0xe0000000-0xe9ffffff 64bit pref]
[    1.006001] pci_bus 0000:28: resource 0 [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    1.006001] pci_bus 0000:28: resource 1 [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc9fffff]
[    1.006002] pci_bus 0000:2a: resource 1 [mem 0xfc600000-0xfc8fffff]
[    1.007011] pci 0000:27:00.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    2.644329] pcieport 0000:00:01.3: AER enabled with IRQ 28
[    2.644349] pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER enabled with IRQ 29
[    2.644369] pcieport 0000:00:03.2: AER enabled with IRQ 30
[    2.644388] pcieport 0000:00:07.1: AER enabled with IRQ 31
[    2.644408] pcieport 0000:00:08.1: AER enabled with IRQ 32
```

I tried to find a reference to this behavior based on the Changelogs and saw that some changes were made to the megaraid_sas module but I'm still a complete newbie in the field of Linux kernels and could not find any help in these.

I would be very grateful for any thoughts

Comment: If the controller doesn’t appear in `lspci` at all, that indicates that something is going wrong during PCI initialisation. You might find relevant information in `dmesg`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for the advice, I´ve added the dmesg log to the post.

Comment: @StephenKitt do you have any ideas for forther debugging?

Comment: Not really... Does it make any difference if you boot with `pci=nocrs`?